# Filter content depending on user access

Tags: views

In Drupal 10, I use the *Permissions by Term* module to restrict user's access to content depending on dictionary values.
I have a content view that does not respect the access permission given by that module.

Is there a way to avoid the logged-in user sees the nodes to which does not have access?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/permissions_by_term?text=views&status=All maybe it's already solved but not merged in ? Can see a few issues around the views integration